# Как вывести текст после выполнения анимации в Android Studio?

Tags: android, listener

Как после выполнения анимации (вращения бутылки) вывести определенный текст на экран? Понимаю, что нужно назначить слушатель, но как на деле должно все выглядеть понимая нет. Вот код анимации:

```
public class ActivityGame extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final Random sRandom = new Random();
    private ImageView mBottleImageView;
    private int lastAngle = -1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game_activity);

        mBottleImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview_bottle);

        mBottleImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                spinBottle();
            }
        });
    }

    private void spinBottle() {
        int angle = sRandom.nextInt(3500-200)+700;
        // Центр вращения
        float pivotX = mBottleImageView.getWidth() / 2;
        float pivotY = mBottleImageView.getHeight() / 2;

        final Animation animation = new RotateAnimation(lastAngle == -1 ? 0 : lastAngle, angle, pivotX, pivotY);
        lastAngle = angle;
        animation.setDuration(3000);
        animation.setFillAfter(true);

        mBottleImageView.startAnimation(animation);
    }
       }
```

Comment: если мой ответ вам помог не проходите даром ставьте лай и принимайте ответ .Это дает мотивацию помогать в будущем

Comment: handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()  выделено красным, конкретно postDelayed, что это?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы правильно говорите, что нужен слушатель:

```
animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        //вывод текст здесь
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void spinBottle() {
            int angle = sRandom.nextInt(3500-200)+700;
            // Центр вращения
            float pivotX = mBottleImageView.getWidth() / 2;
            float pivotY = mBottleImageView.getHeight() / 2;

            final Animation animation = new RotateAnimation(lastAngle == -1 ? 0 : lastAngle, angle, pivotX, pivotY);
            lastAngle = angle;
            animation.setDuration(3000);
            animation.setFillAfter(true);

     final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                          //пихай текс сюда 
                            text=(TextVieü)findViewbyid(R.id.dick);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }, 3000);






            mBottleImageView.startAnimation(animation);
        }
```

Comment: почему у вас всегда такой зубодробительный код? Красивее надо, красивее :)